# How do I start mogodb in this application?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, macos, express, mongodb-nodejs-driver

so this company gave me the assignment to start MongoDB in a couple of on this node js application. I have never used MongoDB and I'm not sure how do I connect with the Database on the application. I only need to connect to the database can you all please help.

Here is the github and im using MacOs catalina :

https://github.com/Garrett-Freddo/kanban-api

Comment: I'd start by consulting the mongodb documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the mongoose package for MongoDB to connect to DB and is also very useful for MongoDB. Just before starting to listen on any port, first, connect to DB, and if successful then you can start your app to listen on any port. You can refer to code in one of [my repo](https://github.com/jatin-parate-mlveda/todo-backend-tdd)